# Powershell: Remove duplicate entries from columns, only keeping first unique value in its original cell of a csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I am pretty new to powershell. I have been trying to remove duplicate entries from columns, only keeping first unique value in its original cell of a csv file.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
1,TestSCript,Test1,Data1,passed
1,TestSCript,Test1,Data2,passed
1,TestSCript,Test2,Data3,passed
1,TestSCript,Test2,Data4,passed
1,TestSCript,Test2,Data5,passed
1,TestSCript,Test3,Data6,passed
1,TestSCript,Test3,Data7,passed
1,TestSCript,Test4,Data8,passed
1,TestSCript,Test5,Data9,passed
```

**Expected Result:**

```
1,TestSCript,Test1,Data1,passed
,,,Data2,passed
,,Test2,Data3,passed
,,,Data4,passed
,,,Data5,passed
,,Test3,Data6,passed
,,,Data7,passed
,,Test4,Data8,passed
,,Test5,Data9,passed
```

Comment: you could build an array of the values as you work thru the input file. then use `$CurrentItem -in $AlreadyThereList` to see if it is new or not.

Comment: The expected result doesn't match your description - I would expect "passed" to only be populated in the first row